# Dynamic numberranges via sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, range, sequence

Business wants different numberranges depending which type of number they want to add. I get the Numberranges always beforehand.

NumberPool

| id | name | range_start | range_end | sequence_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item | 0 | 1000 | seq_items |
| 2 | document | 500 | 1500 | seq_document |
| 3 | item | 1001 | 3000 | seq_items2 |
| 4 | item | 10000 | 11000 | seq_items3 |

NumberTable

| Number_Type | number | more_metadata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item | 1 | foo |
| item | 2 | bar |
| item | ... | bar[numbers to 3 to 999] |
| item | 1000 | foos |
| item | 5000 | bar |
| document | 500 | bar |

I wanted to use identity or sequences to circumvent collisions. I can set start values and max values but I have to react if they are exhausted.

With a procedure I could catch "has reached its minimum or maximum value." and use a different sequence if I have one remaining. Is there a better way to avoid race conditions and still have dynamic number ranges?

Comment: That's a very annoying requirement - you're going to end up spending quite a lot of time maintaining such a numbering scheme. It would much better if you could get rules that allow you to continue generating numbers for a long time.

Comment: Yes you are absolutly right! I have an interface to extend the numbers so I dont have to do it myself, but still its an stupid requirement. Nonetheless it would help if there is some kind of trigger to go by if the pool is exhausted (and change to the next range).

Comment: I think you need a stored procedure to allocate the next sequence number which also checks if the range is exhausted and moves to a new one. Unfortunately this means you have to allocate them one at a time, i.e. you have to force your procedure access to be serial but I can think of Jo other easy way to handle it.

Comment: If I force that procedure to be called one by one I dont even have to use a sequence, and need to implement a mutex on the service side. :\ Thats the reason I asked if there is a better way.

Comment: Yip - no better way that I know... A requirement to keep changing your range is not a normal use case. You can do a mutex equivalent in SQL server.